# How to handle System.OverflowException

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one simple windows application in that amount Textbox is there. When i enter amount into amount textbox it will convert it to words in another textbox named `txtrupees`. Amount Textbox field maximum length is set to 11 places in that last 3 places .00.

My problem is now when i Enter amount with .00 it is working fine. But if i enter 11 places it will giving following Error:

> System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.tried following code.

How can I prevent this kind of error?

```
private void txtamount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtamount.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        string[] amount = txtamount.Text.Split('.');
        if (amount.Length == 2)
        {
            int rs, ps;
            int.TryParse(amount[0], out rs);
            int.TryParse(amount[1], out ps);

            string rupees = words(rs);
            string paises = words(ps);
            txtrupees.Text = rupees + " rupees and " + paises + " paisa only ";
        }
        else if (amount.Length == 1)
        {
            string rupees = words(Convert.ToInt32(amount[0]));
            txtrupees.Text = rupees + " rupees only";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. `Int32` only can hold values up to `2,147,483,647`. If you try to parse a bigger value, it would throw that `OverflowException`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3d0kef1.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue comes from `Convert.ToInt32(amount[0])` where `amount[0]` can be almost anything, including being superior to `Int.MaxValue` or inferior to `Int.MinValue` which would cause an overflow.

Use `int.TryParse(amount[0], out foo);` and use `foo`:

```
else if (amount.Length == 1)
{
    int ps;
    if(int.TryParse(amount[0], out ps))
    {
        string rupees = words(ps);
        txtrupees.Text = rupees + " rupees only";
    }
    else
        txtrupees.Text = "Invalid number";
}
```

If you want to deal with bigger numbers, you can use `Int64`, `Double` or `Decimal`

Comment: If it helped you, you can accept/upvote the answer of your choice. This is the StackOverflow wait to say 'Thanks', @vinnu

Comment: how to write validation for amount textbox it will allow only 8digits and 2 decimal places total 11.If i didn't enter decimal places it should  allow 8 places.If i enter decimal it will take 11 digits .Please help me

Comment: @vinnu this is a different question you're asking. Post a new one explaining what you tried about the validation and why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

a number that has 11 places is larger than a Int32 number. I suggest you should use int64 instead of int32
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx